# PIL save using file object without filename

Tags: save, python-imaging-library

save() has a param fp: A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or file object. If I use file object,what is the filename ? I am inconvenient to test this,please help me!

s = io.BytesIO()

pi = Image.frombytes(mode=i.mode, size=i.size, data=i.data)

pi.save(s, format="jpeg")

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image = Image.new("RGB", (300, 50))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0, 0), 'BytesIO')

byte_io = BytesIO()

image.save(byte_io, 'PNG')
with open('test.png', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(byte_io.getvalue())
```

You still have to do something with the stream like writing to a file after declaring it.

If you want to save the bytes for something:

```
with io.BytesIO() as output:
    image.save(output, 'PNG')
    content = output.getvalue()
```